# Parameter in the argument for lazy evaluation

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to pass varable expression to a lazyeval function:

```
test <- function(expr){
  tmp <- iris[eval(substitute(expr), iris), ]
  #actually do and return complicated stuff with tmp
  return(data.frame(n = nrow(tmp), sepal.length = mean(tmp$Sepal.Length)))
}

test.species <- function(species){
  return(test(Species == substitute(species)))
}

#usage:
test.species("virginica")
```

The function test works just fine. But why is test.species not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substitute(Species == substitute(species))` is evaluated inside `test`, which means `Species` is not compared to a character value, but to a symbol (`substitute(species)`).

`bquote` can be used here instead:

```
test.species <- function(species){
  eval(bquote(test(Species == .(species))))
}
test.species("virginica")
#   n sepal.length
#1 50        6.588
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. As I just found out, eval(substitute(Species == .(species))) would work too. Is there any difference between bquote and substitute here?

Comment: Keep in mind that non-standard evaluation can be nice, but it's usually better to stick with standard evaluation (which, e.g., is easier to debug).

Comment: @HengruiJiang Where do you put that? It shouldn't work.

Comment: Ah I noticed the .() expression.   return(eval(substitute(test(Species == species)))) would work with substitute

Comment: I don't understand. `.()` is syntax specific to `bquote` here. (I cannot rule out that you have loaded a package such as dplyr that defines a `.` function, which might have an effect here.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! It either works with .() and bquote, or just substitute, without .()   That was a mistake in the first comment